# SWRevealController click event does not work, while sliding background works well

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

Using SWRevealViewController, I made a slide view which appears from the right. It is supposed to be triggered by clicking a certain button on the navigation bar or sliding the screen right to left.

The view which appears is displayed in the center of the screenshot.

The problem is that it works only when slid to left, not the button clicked. The following is the code working with the sliding view, which is written in the UIViewController class for the view controller on the right in the screenshot.

The variable 'listBarBtn' is liked to the button with an image of three horizontal lines, a UIBarButtonItem in the right top of the same view.

```
listBarBtn.target = self.revealViewController()
listBarBtn.action =
    #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
self.revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 293
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

The second line was like the following one at first; I was suggested to change it by the compiler.

```
listBarBtn.action = Selector("rightRevealToggle:")
```

And here are the identifiers of the arrows between views:

Reveal View Controller->Vc imozomo Slide: sw_right (reveal view controller set view controller)

Reveal View Controller->Vc info Navigation: sw_front (reveal view controller set view controller)

Vc imozomo Slide->the view on the right with title in korean: myPage(reveal view controller push view controller. In a test project this did not require any identifier but prompted a warning message saying I need one)

[image]

Is there any code I have missed?

---

Answer (score 0):

```
listBarBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
```

is fine.

does `listBarBtn` connect to your view controller as an `IBOutlet`? or 
does it cover with the bell image?

did you check the UIBarButtonItem is clickable?

Comment: `listBarBtn` is linked like this: `@IBOutlet var listBarBtn: UIBarButtonItem!`, the list image does not cover the bell. And how can I check if the `UIBarButtonItem` is set as clickable? The attributes inspector doesn't show any attribute with title of 'clickable' or something similar to that.

Comment: How about you add weak '@IBOutlet weak var listBarBtn: UIBarButtonItem!' 

and

There is an checkbox option called "Enabled" when you select your bar button item in storyboard.

Comment: I added `weak` keyword but it didn't make any change. And the 'Enabled' checkbox was checked as true before I add the keyword.

Comment: Reveal View Controller->Vc info Navigation: sw_front (reveal view controller set view controller)

How about you try SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController instead of SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController

Comment: then the screen turns into black. The reveal view controller is linked from the initial view controller by a UIButton and it happens when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the segue identifier as sw_right for right reveal. sw_rear will reveal left while the sw_right will slide the right menu.
 [image]

Comment: If you are talking about the one to the slid view, yes. The other one is set as sw_front.